# Magento 2 Where can I find a xml file location?

Tags: magento2, xml, locations

Where can I find the location of `customer/create_account/email_identity`?

```
const XML_PATH_REGISTER_EMAIL_IDENTITY = 'customer/create_account/email_identity';
```

Answer (score 3):

It is located at

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/config.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Its location inside `{{magentoroot}}/vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/config.xml` at line no. 19. value getting `general`.